# Lack of precision using float and BigDecimal while setting opacity of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, fade, precision, bigdecimal

I hope the title makes sense; I'm trying to create a fade-in effect using a `SwingWorker` to set the opacity of the undecorated frame.

I get an exception for attempting to set the frame's opacity above `1.0`. When I print out each increment on the opacity, these were the results:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.70000005
0.8000001
0.9000001
```

I tried using `BigDecimal`, hoping to somehow keep precision, but it failed. This is the code for my SwingWorker:

```
private JFrame frame; //initialized in constructor of class

private SwingWorker<Void, Void> fadeIn = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(".1");

        while(frame.getOpacity() < 1.0f)
            try {
                System.out.println(frame.getOpacity());
                frame.setOpacity(frame.getOpacity() + decimal.floatValue());
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

    public void done() {
        System.out.println("done");
    }
};
```

The fade-in works fine up until I get this exception (code above doesn't catch; must manually catch):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value of opacity should be in the range [0.0f .. 1.0f].
    at java.awt.Window.setOpacity(Window.java:3609)
    at java.awt.Frame.setOpacity(Frame.java:962)
    at gui.Splash$1.doInBackground(Splash.java:19)
    at gui.Splash$1.doInBackground(Splash.java:1)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there any way to get better precision out of this? I understand I could use an `AlphaComposite` and override the paint method, but I'm hoping I can keep it as simple as it currently is.

Is there any way I can get more precision to ensure I don't increase opacity above what it's allowed?

Comment: `frame.getOpacity() + decimal.floatValue()`  defeats the purpose of the BigDecimal as you are using it at as a float

Comment: @vandale I figured that, since `floatValue()` returns a primitive float. I'm still unsure of how to tackle this problem without resorting to overriding the paint method and using the alphacomposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run your own values, forget about what the current opacity is:

```
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        try {
            frame.setOpacity(i/10.0);
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}
```

This way you're guaranteed to end up at `1.0`.

Comment: `frame.setOpacity(i/10.0);` should be inside `publish/process` or `setProcess` (done on EDT), instead of wrong doInBackground(by default never notified EDT),  :-) sorry more in API :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a float and the then take the min of the float and 1.0 to ensure it is in the range:

```
frame.setOpacity(Math.Min(frame.getOpacity() + 0.1f, 1.0f));
```